# Backward compatibility Material design

Tags: android

How do I use material design . here is my `gradle`.

I want to use the material in my app. I want to maintain the min target as 9.

Please help

```
 pply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 3
            versionName "1.0.1"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2'
    }
```

Comment: The code is okay. what should I add to dependency to use material design? . I understand its only for api 21 and above  and my min sdk is 9.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a new project is created in Android Studio, by default it comes with an attached AppCompat v7 library. Make sure that this support library is r21. As this new release supports backward compatibility with material design. To include it in you project add the line below in your :app build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

You can utilize the AppCompat library for displaying material theme by including code below in your regular styles.xml:

```
styles.xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

or define the new layouts for v21(Android Lollipop), in `res/layout-v21` folder of your project. Your app will show these layout only when an Android 5.0 device is in use.